# Realizar um cálculo de valores anteriores em coluna no R

Tags: python, r, microsoft-excel

Gostaria de montar uma coluna de acordo com o resultado de 2 linhas de uma outra coluna, segue a fórmula abaixo, não faço ideia de como montar isso no R ou no Python e gostaria de uma colaboração de vocês.

Dando um exemplo no Excel

```
                coluna 1   coluna 2
      célula D2 - 558,8       1
      célula D3 - 584,3       1
      célula D4 - 603,3   =SE(D4-D2>=D2*0,02;1;SE(D4-D2<=-D2*0,02;-1;0))
```

E assim sucessivamente...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez isso te ajude, utilizando **dplyr**

Data frame de teste

```
dados <- data.frame(coluna_1 = c(558.8, 584.3, 603.3))
```

A lógica

```
library(dplyr)

dados <- dados %>% mutate(coluna_2 = case_when(
  coluna_1 - lag(coluna_1, n = 2) >=  lag(coluna_1, n = 2) * 0.02 ~ 1,
  coluna_1 - lag(coluna_1, n = 2) <=  (-lag(coluna_1, n = 2)) * 0.02 ~ -1,
  T ~ 0 
))
dados$coluna_2[1:2] <- 1
```

Com mutate criamos uma coluna nova chamada coluna_2, o **case_when** serve para fazer algo quando uma condição é aceita, o **lag** serve para dar um atraso, neste caso damos um **lag** de 2 que seriam duas linhas acima. O T ~ 0 é quando nenhuma condição foi encontrada então preenchemos com 0.

---

Obs: Como o calculo é feito voltando duas linhas os primeiros resultados vão ser zero, pois não tem como calcular.

---

Uma possibilidade em Python utilizando o pandas

```
import pandas as pd

dados = pd.DataFrame({'coluna_1': [558.8, 584.3, 603.3]})

dados.loc[dados['coluna_1'] - dados['coluna_1'].shift(2) >= dados['coluna_1'].shift(2) * 0.02, 'coluna_2'] = 1
dados.loc[dados['coluna_1'] - dados['coluna_1'].shift(2) <= -dados['coluna_1'].shift(2) * 0.02, 'coluna_2'] = -1
dados['coluna_2'].iloc[0:2] = 1
dados.fillna(0)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela aula, me ajudou muito, teria alguma maneira de deixar os dos primeiros itens com o valor 1?

Comment: @RoneyWesleyGalan, boa tarde! Como os dois primeiros valores não entram nas condições de preenchimento do restante, podemos colocar 1 de forma arbitrária. Atualizei o código para resolver essa questão. Se as condições sempre forem atingidas, você pode colocar o fill_na ou o T ~ iguais a 1 pois serão os unicos resultados faltantes. Exemplo: `fill_na(1)` ou em R `T ~ 1` Abraço!

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Me ajudou demais, um dia chego nesse nível expert rsrs.

Comment: @RoneyWesleyGalan, por nada! precisando estamos ai! Com certeza vai chegar! Abraço!!!

Answer (score 2):

Aqui está uma solução em R base, vetorizada com `sign`.

```r
n <- nrow(dados)
inx <- seq_len(n)[-(1:2)]
dados$col2 <- 1
dados$col2[inx] <- sign(dados$col1[inx] - 1.02*dados$col1[inx - 2])
```

**Dados de teste**

```r
col1 <- c(558.8, 584.3, 603.3)
dados <- data.frame(col1)
```